# unable to access a .csv file using java script in html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, d3.js, xampp

I am trying to grasp [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) to get visual data representation and in one of the tutorials provided there, i tried to run one of the code which is taking a .csv file as a input and then using required svg methods and java script displaying it on the web-page.

Well when i tried to run the below code, it didn't work out.I had xampp installed in my system.I had kept the j3s.html in the httpdocs folder and the .csv file in the same folder, but some how its not working.

I am totally new to the web and java script but yes this code is easily understandable.Below is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viz"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

d3.text("auto_mpg_tmp.csv", function(datasetText) {

var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parseRows(datasetText);

var sampleHTML = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("table")
    .style("border-collapse", "collapse")
    .style("border", "2px black solid")

    .selectAll("tr")
    .data(parsedCSV)
    .enter().append("tr")

    .selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d){return d;})
    .enter().append("td")
    .style("border", "1px black solid")
    .style("padding", "5px")
    .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color", "aliceblue")})
    .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("background-color", "white")})
    .text(function(d){return d;})
    .style("font-size", "12px");
});

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Well there are lots of problems with my XAMPP also and i tried to figure them out using [this link](https://drupal.org/node/161975).
here is the error log of xampp server.

```
4:17:41 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
4:17:41 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
4:17:41 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
4:17:41 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
4:17:41 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
4:17:41 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
4:17:41 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is with your server-stack.  But the Javascript code seems fine.  I have it **[running intact on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/OtiziRo/1/edit)**.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest for you is going to use the Python webserver for development, instead of the whole XAMPP stack.

Make sure that Python is installed. In the directory containing your top-level `index.html` (the contents of which you pasted above), simply do:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

This will startup a mini-webserver that you can access by entering the following into your browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```